# Writing a function to combine arrays from different files

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for the novice question.  I'm just starting to learn Python and I don't have any coding background.  I already ended up doing this process manually, but I'm curious what the automated process would look like and would like to learn from the example.

So I have a folder of 50 npz files.  I need to pull a specific 29x5 array from each npz file and concatenate all of it into a single csv.  This is what I did manually:

```
import numpy as np
import os
os.chdir('D:/Documents/WorkingDir')
data1=np.load('file1.npz', mmap_mode='r')
array1 = data1.f.array
#data2=etc.
#array2=etc.
grandarray = np.concatenate((array1,array2), axis = 0)
np.savetext('grandarray.csv', grandarrray, delimiter=",")
```

I gather you can use glob to get a list of all files in the same folder with the .npz extension, but I can't figure out how to turn my manual process into a script and automate it.  I'll gladly take links to tutorial websites that can get me going in this direction as well.  Thank you all for your time.

Comment: What's the point of `array1 = data.f.array`? There is no variable defined with the name `data`. Is it just a typo, and you meant to write `array1 = data.f.array`?

Comment: Yes that's just a typo.  should be `array1 = data1.f.array.` Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use iteration. A loop would be fine, but I find a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to be acceptable here.

```py
import glob
import numpy as np
import os


os.chdir('D:/Documents/WorkingDir')
filenames = glob.glob('*.npz')
data_arrays = [np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r').f.array for filename in filenames]
grandarray = np.concatenate(data_arrays, axis = 0)
np.savetext('grandarray.csv', grandarrray, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had to change a line in the np.load so it reads `[np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')['array']` because the `np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r').f.array` command was returning this error `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`.  I probably just need to read up on how np.load actually works.

Comment: Nice job. You also may consider using an actual csv writer rather than `np.savetxt`. Depending on the values in those arrays you could corrupt the data, e.g. if any of the values contain commas. The `csv` module is a good place to start https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv